# Using GMail as an interface to my database

Tags: gmail, email

What if I choose to use GMail's awesome mail archive search capabilities on my database? What if, for every transaction that my database is responsible, I emailed details of that transaction to a GMail address that exists for the sole purpose of searching and retrieving transactions.

Anyone logged into that account could search according to labels, invoice numbers, customer names - whatever using Google's search engine. The results are presented as 'email messages'.

Imagine a user working from the standard (web-based) GMail account searches for an invoice number via GMail's search box - he's returned all instances where the db did anything that included that unique number. Opening any of these 'email messages' would have the static text text included at the time of the transactions (historical and tracking gold) but could also carry a Gadget that could transform the 'message' into an editor so as to execute a new transaction on that invoice.

Imagine further that I wasn't the first one to think of this - cuz surely i'm not - and even if i were, i'm not smart enough to execute the idea alone.

Are you aware of efforts similar to this?

thx

[?belongs on superuser instead?]

Answer (score 0):

An interesting idea, however given your search parameters it might be unreliable. Although gmail's search is great, I have found issues when searching for partial terms. Case in point, I had an email whose subject line was "stuffas". When I searched for "stuffa" I got no results, when I searched for "stuffas" I got the email in the search result. Additionally, I had an email with an 8 digit number inside the body. When I searched for 7 digits out of 8, I got no results, but when I put all 8 digits, the email appeared in the results. So, search in gmail may not be as powerful of a solution as you think. Again this is my experience, I'd love to hear if someone is able to partial search numbers in gmail.

Comment: I'm aware to of the requirement to exact match but in this context it wouldn't be a limitation. 95% of the lookups (in this context) are in response to a client calling in to ask about an invoice # that they are looking at.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same idea; 4 years after you. It still doesn't look like this has 'been done before' in any production sense. But now in 2014, I really don't see why not. Python packages for interfacing with gmail are already there and dead-simple to use. It does not take a whole lot of abstraction to turn this into a generalized key-value storage.

Its probably not exactly the fastest database, and not the best solution for everything; but as an easy-to-use, easy to search, trivial to configure, 100% uptime, cloud stored and backed up, free-as-in-beer database, its pretty epic as far as I can see.

Anyone else has seen examples of this having been done before?

Edit: having thought about it some more, there are several answers as to why this is a bad idea:

- gmail does not permit random access from different locations; it will block you account. quite a showstopper
- amazon simpleDB also gives you a simple key-value store with the same characteristics (plus good python support), and isn't THAT big of a pain to set up if you are willing to spend a day wrapping your head around it. And is also effectively free for the kind of traffic that youd be able to cram into a gmail account.